# Continue to run a batch file in a new console

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-console

Is there any way that you can continue to run a batch script in a new console. I have a large batch script and I would like it to be able to spawn cmd shells attached to new consoles. Those cmd intsances will continue to run the script, another part of the script, or display data; it does not matter. Also the main script should stay open, so I can rerun commands again if needed.

Comment: If you use call in front of your new shell command then the batch file will continue running: call cmd another.bat

Comment: That's the point I don't want to call another .bat file. I would like main one to create new cmd window and continue to run script in new window.

Comment: `start` opens a console program such as cmd.exe in a new console (it's not a cmd window), without waiting for it to exit.

Comment: You can't continue a batch file in a new window...

Answer (score 1):

The generic workaround when you need this sort of behaviour is an old-fashioned goto.  (You're using a dinosaur-era language, so sometimes you're going to need dinosaur-era tools.)

On the first line of your batch file,

```
@if "%1" == "/goto" goto :%2
```

When you want to launch a separate instance of your batch file, starting from a particular label,

```
start cmd /c "%0" /goto mylabel
```

A complete example:

```
if "%1" == "/goto" goto :%2

echo Hello!

start cmd /c "%0" /goto mylabel

echo Goodbye!

goto :eof

:mylabel

echo Hello!

pause
```

Comment: Data can be passed on the command line, in environment variables, temporary files, or registry keys. Actions can be synchronized with waitfor.exe, which is based on the little-used [Mailslots](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365576).

Comment: Unfortunately, anonymous pipes won't work because creating a new console resets the standard handle values. The process will inherit the pipe handle, but it will have no way to use it.